# why request object in Symfony 2.8 service is empty?

Tags: php, symfony, service, request

in Symfony 2.8 service have this service:

```
services:
    app.admin_menu:
        class: GRF\AdminPanelBundle\Service\Menu
        shared: false
        arguments: [@request_stack]
```

and in service construct :

```
public function __construct(RequestStack $request)
{
    exit(var_dump($request));
}
```

and in browser :

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack)#261 (1) { ["requests":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack":private]=> array(0) { } }
```

how can access current request in service ??? now current request is null

Comment: Did you try  with `$request->getCurrentRequest()`?

Comment: The service is being created before the request is even processed.  Store the injected requestStack then grab the request from it when you actually need it.

Comment: $request->getCurrentRequest() is nulled

Comment: thanks Cerad , request not available in service construct , i can use it in another method

Comment: you can still do it like that, but you need to set the scope of the service to request ("scope: request"). That might have other disadvantages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630670/how-to-generate-absolute-url-from-early-auto-loaded-symfony-3-router/43634938#43634938).

The solution is to try and access the RequestStack object as late as possible to give the kernel a chance to populate it.

Essentially, don't try access it in the constructor.

I moved my access of it out into a method that is called later and it solved it for me.

```
private $requestStack;

public function __construct(RequestStack $request)
{
    $this->requestStack = $request;
}

public function outputRequestStack() {
    exit(var_dump($this->requestStack));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`RequestStack` is an object, which contain several requests (used for internal forwarding and esi). To extract `Request` object from it you can call `$request = requestStack->getMasterRequest();`