# How to generate Absolute URL from Early/Auto loaded Symfony 3 router

Tags: php, symfony, routes, autoload

I am writing Guards to handle OAuth for my Symfony 3 application.

As part of it, in one of my services, I need to generate an absolute URL to send to Twitter as the Callback URL.

```
#services.yml
...
app.twitter_client:
    class: MyApiBundle\Services\TwitterClient
    arguments:
        - %twitter_client_id%
        - %twitter_client_secret%
        - connect_twitter_check
        - '@request_stack'
        - '@router'
        - '@logger'
app.twitter_authenticator:
    class: MyApiBundle\Security\TwitterAuthenticator
    arguments:
        - '@app.twitter_client'
        - '@logger'
```

The logger is temporary for debugging.

```
#TwitterClient.php service
...
use Monolog\Logger;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
class TwitterClient
{

/**
 * TwitterClient constructor.
 * @param string          $identifier
 * @param string          $secret
 * @param string          $callbackUrl
 * @param RequestStack    $requestStack
 * @param RouterInterface $router
 * @param Logger          $logger
 */
public function __construct(
    string $identifier,
    string $secret,
    string $callbackUrl,
    RequestStack $requestStack,
    RouterInterface $router,
    Logger $logger
) {
    $callbackUrl = $router->generate($callbackUrl, [], RouterInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
    $logger->info($callbackUrl);
    ...
}
```

And when it outputs the `$callbackUrl` to the logs, it just says localhost, even though I am accessing it using a different URL.

```
http://localhost/connect/twitter/check
```

But if I do the same from my a controller, it outputs the full proper URL.

```
#TwitterController.php
...
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;


class TwitterController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/connect/twitter")
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function connectAction()
    {
        /** @var RouterInterface $router */
        $router = $this->container->get('router');
        $callbackUrl = $router->generate('connect_twitter_check', [], RouterInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
        /** @var Logger $logger */
        $logger = $this->container->get('logger');
        $this->container->get('logger')
            ->info($callbackUrl);
        ...
```

This outputs:

```
https://dev.myapi.com:8082/app_dev.php/connect/twitter/check
```

The `dev.myapi.com` domain is set up in my hosts file and points to localhost, to make it easier to differentiate between my local apps and also to make it easier to integrate with OAuth services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by setting the Router context.
I already loaded in the RequestStack to access the user's IP, so I used it to set the context of the Route and then the router worked as expected.
I ran into [problems](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17273#issuecomment-297648646) trying to use the RequestStack in the constructor, so I ended up refactoring it so that it used the RequestStack as late as possible.

```
class TwitterClient
{
    private $identifier;
    private $secret;
    private $callbackUrl;
    private $requestStack;
    private $router;
    private $server;

    /**
     * TwitterClient constructor.
     *
     * @param string          $identifier
     * @param string          $secret
     * @param string          $callbackUrl
     * @param RequestStack    $requestStack
     * @param RouterInterface $router
     */
    public function __construct(
        string $identifier,
        string $secret,
        string $callbackUrl,
        RequestStack $requestStack,
        RouterInterface $router
    ) {
        $this->identifier = $identifier;
        $this->secret = $secret;
        $this->callbackUrl = $callbackUrl;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * Wait until the last moment to create the Twitter object to make sure that the requestStack is loaded.
     *
     * @return \League\OAuth1\Client\Server\Twitter
     */
    private function getServer()
    {
        if (!$this->server) {
            $context = new RequestContext();
            $context->fromRequest($this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest());
            $this->router->setContext($context);
            $callbackUrl = $this->router->generate($this->callbackUrl, [], RouterInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
            $this->server = new Twitter(
                [
                    'identifier' => $this->identifier,
                    'secret' => $this->secret,
                    'callback_uri' => $callbackUrl,
                ]
            );
        }

        return $this->server;
    }
    ...
}
```